# get element from array matching with file expension

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I get element from array matching with pdf?
Here is my code. I have getting one value '38.pdf'. But I need 38.pdf and 39.pdf.

```
$encrypt             = md5(Auth::user()->id.$selectFile->created_at);
$directories         = Storage::files($encrypt);   
// dd($directories)                                      
foreach($directories as $values){
 $split_folder_file = explode('/', $values); 
 $splitted_file     = end($split_folder_file);
 $userdata          = 'userdata';
 $filenameresult    = storage_path().'/'.$userdata.'/'.$encrypt.'/'.$splitted_file;
 return response()->download($filenameresult, $splitted_file, ['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf']);
}
```

**Result of dd(directories) is**

```
array:3 [
      0 => "30e9734e1f06bf751da5b3289994fb3f/38.pdf"
      1 => "30e9734e1f06bf751da5b3289994fb3f/39.pdf"
      2 => "30e9734e1f06bf751da5b3289994fb3f/Profile.jpg"
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can first show a page with links like :

===========

you have 2 elements PDF to download :

```
 <a>38.pdf</a>
 <a>39.pdf</a>
 .
 .
 .
```

=============

and when the user click the link it will redirect to the code :

```
return response()->download(
     $filenameresult, $splitted_file, ['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf']
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_grep for example. It will return an array with the matches

```
$pdf = preg_grep('/\/.*\.pdf$/', $directories );
print_r( $pdf );
```